# JQueryMobile or Ionic for my project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework

I am planning to make a project based on server side application.
I can choose which options will shown on phone applications via server side.

For example. There are 10 types of filters in server side. I want the mobile app to show 3 of them. So I choose 3 types of filters (like radio button, input text etc) in the mobile side. I then send request to display selected filter or template type on screen. I have to create almost all my html with Javascript in mobile side.

Could you suggest me which one to use, JQueryMobile or Ionic Framework?Which of these is the easiest choice for this application. Which one of them offer me creating templates dynamically?

Comment: Ionic becuase it will use Angular and you can easly do filtering using angular js.

Comment: I mean filter types are my templates.I don't mean angular filter.. sorry for hard explaining

Comment: no prob .According to me Ionic is better for this. jquery mobile is little lazy.

Comment: yeah I like ionic as well.but my app based on close DOM manipulations.it is more easy on jquerymobile.that's why I wonder which one of them is better.

Comment: aren't you trying to pitch YOUR technology of choice ? In that case this discussion hold no point. Go with jQuery Mobile because that is technology of choice for you anyways.

My two cents goes to IONIC as well.

Comment: I already know both.but not that much good at jquerymobile.so I don't know disadvantage of it.it is so easy DOM maniplations with it.but I don't know lack of it.developping with ionic is easy and clear, but I don't know, is it reliable for this application because of DOM..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic because

1. Ionic has an AngularJS backend.
2. jQuery Mobile was not updated in last two years, even then it wasn't the fastest solution for mobile development. Version 1.5 will come out soon, and it will bring jQuery UI integration.
3. Ionic is currently best available hybrid mobile framework. If you don't like this statement then consider it mostly used framework.
4. Ionic is faster than JQueryMobile.

If you want DOM Manipulation, You can use Custom Directives in Angular to manipulate your DOM in much easier way than JQuery.

In Short:

If you have a previous jQuery knowledge, alredy built logic in Jquery and you don't have time to learn AngularJS stick with jQuery Mobile.

In any other case choose Ionic.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation.I'll consider your explanation. +1